# How to pass some variable values to RML file in Python?

Tags: python, reportlab

Given an RML template, used to generate PDF file in python, how can one use variables declared in a Python script in the RML template file?

```
def create_pdf:
   name = "My Name"

   with open('/file.rml') as rml:
         data = rml.read()
   pdf = rml2pdf.parseString(data)
   with open(f"/newpdf.pdf", 'wb') as output:
         output.write(pdf.read())
   return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

Here is the template `file.rml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no" ?> 
<!DOCTYPE document SYSTEM "rml_1_0.dtd">
<document filename="file.rml">
   .....
    <story>
        <para style="h1-center">[[name]]</para> <!-- Name value should appear here -->
    </story>
</document>
```

So how do I get the name variable value in the template?

Answer (score 0):

You may preprocess your file with genshi:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no" ?> 
<!DOCTYPE document SYSTEM "rml_1_0.dtd">
<document xmlns:py="http://genshi.edgewall.org/" filename="file.rml">
   .....
    <story>
        <para style="h1-center" py:content="name" /> <!-- Name value should appear here -->
    </story>
</document>
```

Genshi template > RML file > PDF

https://genshi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templates/